# Passing Values from a JSP page to a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jsp, servlets

I have a jsp page that updates what is listed based on the selection in a box.

```
<form:select path="Value" id="select" onchange="update()" items="${Values}" />
```

And in another file the corresponding update function that populates based on what you selected and the item.  This works for one box, but I need to have multiple boxes, but copying the code into a for loop generates multiple boxes, but the update function only points to the id of the object "select".  I want to create a way to have select to be variable, so that it generates multiple objects with different values so that they don't point to the same thing.

My thought was to just create a var and then have it count, so that at  id="select" can force it to create different objects... but the update function reads from the jsp with

```
var Val = $('#select option:selected').val();
```

In order to make them match, I need to pass parameters into the update() function, but when I fill in update method with parameters, the JSP can no longer call it.  I tried
   Update(var n) { //code here}
and
   Update(int n) {//Code here}

But when the JSP statement runs update(//ValueIwant), it always throws the error of not finding the method.

So my question is , how can I pass a parameter from a jsp page to the javascript function dynamically without  hardcoding all the values.

Comment: I couldn't quite understand your question but try this. Put your select in for loop with "i" as counter  and change the id of the select to id="select"+i.

Comment: What does the JSP tag `form:` prefix stand for? What taglib are you using?

Comment: Is that Spring MVC you're using?

Comment: Your question is confusing. Do you realize that JSP is merely a HTML code generator? And that JavaScript is just part of that generated HTML (and thus you should be writing JSP code that way that it generates exactly the desired HTML/JS code so that it can run without trouble in the webbrowser). Just checking the generated HTML output by rightclick and *View Source* in webbrowser may already give a lot of clues as to the concrete problem which you seem to have in JavaScript side.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out. It's pretty simple. Just call the function(Parameters) from JSP, but in the javascript, the method is just declared with the parameter not having a type.

```
Function Myfunction (N)
{
//code
}
```

Comment: Yes, variables have no type declaration in javascript. And functions have no capital F ;-) => `function MyFunction(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

In **this specific situation**, the javascript keyword `this` can be used to pass along the reference of the element.

Staying as close as possible with provided code (including jQuery use), this would be:

```
<form:select path="Value" id="select" onchange="update(this)" items="${Values}" />
<!-- 3 more times; id should be changed and kept unique -->
<!-- ... -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  function update(srcElement) {
    var Val = $(srcElement).find('option:selected').val();
    // want to make sure it's OK so far?
    console.log(Val);
  }
</script>
```

---

Now, **in the general case**, as others have mentioned, it's essentially a question of how you use the JSP tags so as to generate HTML (and here embedded javascript) that does what you want it to do.

I haven't practiced Spring MVC (I assume that's what is being used here), but in **pseudo-code**, this could look like:

```
<!-- remember? this is *pseudo-code*, 
     for I ignore the form:select capabilities,
     specifically towards runtime expressions like ${i} 
-->
<% for(int i= 0; i<4 ; i++) { %>
  <%-- maybe the following line is not 100% OK; 
       fix it according to your taglib documentation --%>
  <form:select path="Value" id="select${i}" 
               onchange="update(${i})" items="${Values}" />
<% } %>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function update(index) {
    var Val = $('#select' + index + ' option:selected').val();
    // want to make sure it's OK so far?
    console.log(Val);
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Should be worth stating the obvious: **whenever possible, using `this` is more robust and easier to implement**.